# Converting .NodeJS Authentication Token script to Apps Script

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script

I am a newer Apps Scripts user who has been stuck on this problem for some time. I am trying to connect my company's reporting feature to a Google Sheet so I can create reporting dashboards for our users.

I have a .jsNode code snippet which I am able to successfully run outside of the Apps Scripts editor, but I am having issues translating it to Apps Scripts.

My goal is to be able to generate an Authentication Token which will be used in a header within a POST request. I will then use this to get a specific URL that I can pull data from (it will be a .csv file. I already feel I can accomplish this using another script)

Below is the .NodeJS code snippet:

```html
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports.init = function () {
    let prefix = 'abc-admin-v1'
    let businessId = 'XXXX'
    let publicAppKeyId = 'XXXX'
    let secretKey = 'XXXX'
    let unixTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    let payload = `${prefix}${businessId}${unixTimestamp}`
    let rawKey = Buffer.from(secretKey, 'base64')
    let signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', rawKey).update(payload, 'utf8').digest('base64')
    let token = `${signature}${payload}`
    let httpBasicPayload = `${publicAppKeyId}:${token}`
    let httpBasicCredentials = Buffer.from(httpBasicPayload, 'utf8').toString('base64')

    console.log(httpBasicCredentials);
};
```

Below will be what I have in Apps Scripts:

```html
function apiInfo() {
  var secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var apiKey = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var locationID = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";  

  var prefix = "abc-admin-v1";
  var timeStamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
  var timeStampReal = JSON.stringify(timeStamp);

  var tokenPayload = prefix + businessID + timeStampReal;
  var enCodeTokenPayload = Utilities.base64Encode(tokenPayload);
  var deCodeTokenPayload = Utilities.base64Decode(enCodeTokenPayload);
  var tokenPayloadReal = JSON.stringify(tokenPayload);

  var rawKey = Utilities.base64Decode(secret);
  var rawMac = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(tokenPayloadReal, rawKey);
  var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(rawMac);

  var token = signature + tokenPayload;

  var httpBasicPayload = apiKey + ":" + token;
  var httpBasicCredentials = Utilities.base64Encode(httpBasicPayload);
```

When testing using the current GAS code, it produces an invalid Auth Token.

When I run the Node.js version outside of GAS, it produces a valid Auth Token. I am looking to find out what is currently wrong with my code that is producing an invalid auth token. I would like to keep the project within GAS if possible.

Comment: From `I am unsure if my problem is due to my query, or if it's caused by the token not being translated to Apps Script properly`, in this case, first, when if your Node.js script returns the correct value, how about testing whether your "Below is the .NodeJS code snippet:" works? From this result, I thought that you can know whether your query is correct.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated my Node.js code and it successfully runs outside of Apps Scripts

so I would need to translate that piece to Apps Scripts. I manually copy and pasted the Auth Code, and when running my function with that, I do receive an error:
- "{"errors":[{"message":"No query document supplied"}]}"

this means my GraphQL query is not working also(I can resolve this part of the question on my own I think)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I couldn't understand your current issue. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike ! I am looking to create an Apps Scripts equivalent of the Node.js code snippet. I want to generate an Auth Token using that script, and use it for a task. Let me know if I can clarify further!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I am looking to create an Apps Scripts equivalent of the Node.js code snippet.`, I understand that you wanted to convert your Node.js to Google Apps Script. But, in your question, you say `I am unsure if my problem is due to my query, or if it's caused by the token not being translated to Apps Script properly`. So, I cannot still understand your goal. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , I have updated my question to just limit to the authentication token scripts. I can test whether or not the Authentication Token works with my query in a different environment.

Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you so much! I have seen your other answers on SO and it was great to see how you would solve this problem that I have been having, much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert your showing Node.js script to Google Apps Script. Namely, you want to retrieve the same values of `httpBasicCredentials` between your Node.js script and Google Apps Script.

  ```
    const crypto = require('crypto');

    module.exports.init = function () {
        let prefix = 'abc-admin-v1'
        let businessId = 'XXXX'
        let publicAppKeyId = 'XXXX'
        let secretKey = 'XXXX'
        let unixTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
        let payload = `${prefix}${businessId}${unixTimestamp}`
        let rawKey = Buffer.from(secretKey, 'base64')
        let signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', rawKey).update(payload, 'utf8').digest('base64')
        let token = `${signature}${payload}`
        let httpBasicPayload = `${publicAppKeyId}:${token}`
        let httpBasicCredentials = Buffer.from(httpBasicPayload, 'utf8').toString('base64')

        console.log(httpBasicCredentials);
    };
  ```

When I saw your showing Google Apps Script, unfortunately, there are several undeclared variable and unused variables. By this, in this answer, I would like to propose to directly converting your showing Node.js to Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let prefix = 'abc-admin-v1'
  let businessId = 'XXXX'
  let publicAppKeyId = 'XXXX'
  let secretKey = 'XXXX'
  let unixTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  let payload = `${prefix}${businessId}${unixTimestamp}`;
  let payloadBytes = Utilities.newBlob(payload).getBytes();
  let rawKey = Utilities.base64Decode(secretKey);
  let signature = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(payloadBytes, rawKey));
  let token = `${signature}${payload}`;
  let httpBasicPayload = `${publicAppKeyId}:${token}`;
  let httpBasicCredentials = Utilities.base64Encode(httpBasicPayload);
  console.log(httpBasicCredentials);
}
```

#### Testing:

In the above scripts, when the value of `unixTimestamp` is `1661403828`, both your Node.js and my sample Google Apps Script are the same values as follows.

```
WFhYWDpGYXBwRk9kaFoxdDVQNGVkV2JJbFIvR1RiMkEyZ0hwYThld05BYjVDVkxnPWFiYy1hZG1pbi12MVhYWFgxNjYxNDAzODI4
```

#### Note:

- From your question, in this answer, your Node.js is converted to Google Apps Script. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata_1)
- [computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue,-key)